# Reset html form using javascript only when a condition is satisfied

Tags: javascript, function, debugging, reset

I have a code where I need to reset the html form if the text entered into the textbox doesn't match the predefined ones. However if I use the reset() function, the form is reset even if the text matches the predefined text. How do I avoid this problem? here's my code.

```
    function showData() {
    var code= document.getElementById("bcno").value.trim();
    switch(code)
    {
        case "WASTE1":
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML ="This Is Waste Type 1.";
        break;
        case "WASTE2":
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML ="This Is Waste Type 2.";
        break;
        case "WASTE3":
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML ="This Is Waste Type 3.";
        break;
        case "WASTE4":
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML ="This Is Waste Type 4.";
        break;
        default:
        setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("updateform").reset();}, 2000);
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML ="The text does not match. Form will be reset momentarily!!.";
        break;

    }
```

Heres's the html part.

```
    <form action="dbupdate.php" method="post" id="updateform" 
     name="updateform"> 
    <label for="bcno">Item ID: </label>
    <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" name="bcno" id="bcno" 
    oninput="showData()" autocomplete="off" /> <br /><br /> 
    <div id="display"></div> 
    <label for="ino">Quantity: </label>
    <input type="number" id="ino" name="ino" value="1" /><br /><br /> 
    <input type="button" onclick="document.updateform.submit();" 
    value="Confirm"> </form>
```

**bcno** is the id of the textbox. What am i doing wrong?
 Also I am using **Google Chrome** (version 63.0.3239.132, the latest) to test my code

Comment: Do messages "This Is Waste Type X." get displayed when the right codes are entered?

Comment: Yes. and they stay. but the form gets reset. I cant have that since I have to forward the data to another page.

Comment: Where do you use this function? Do you use it when submitting the form? Please share your `HTML` code.

Comment: `<form action="dbupdate.php" method="post" id="updateform" name="updateform">
<label for="bcno">Item ID: </label>
<input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" name="bcno" id="bcno" oninput="showData()" autocomplete="off" />
<br /><br />
<div id="display"></div>
<label for="ino">Quantity: </label><input type="number" id="ino" name="ino" value="1" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="document.updateform.submit();" value="Confirm">
</form>`

Comment: i've updated the question as aswell if you cant get it from the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got what I was doing wrong.
I had been using the **oninput** event in my textbox which called the function as soon as a character was entered into the textbox.
I substituted it with the **onchange** event. Now it works fine. Thanks anyways guys.

Answer (score 0):

The form will be reset only when the reset() method is called. Always you see the "The text does not match" alone getting printed even if the value matches the predefined text? Try to put a console.log(code) before the switch block to find the value read from the input field.

Comment: Nope. it works as it should. when the correct text is entered, it shows the the defined text in display. It just resets the form.

Comment: when i use the console.log() function it loads the following:

Comment: W
Update data.php:10  WA
Update data.php:10  WAS
Update data.php:10  WAST
Update data.php:10  WASTE
Update data.php:10  WASTE1

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript `Switch` Statement, you can do this. But using `Regular Expressions` is much better.

```js
var myTimer;

function showData() {
    var code = document.getElementById( 'bcno' ).value.trim().toUpperCase(),
        disp = document.getElementById( 'display' );

    switch ( code ) {
        case 'W':
        case 'WA':
        case 'WAS':
        case 'WAST':
        case 'WASTE':
            break;
        case 'WASTE1':
            disp.innerHTML ="This Is Waste Type 1.";
            break;
        case 'WASTE2':
            disp.innerHTML ="This Is Waste Type 2.";
            break;
        case 'WASTE3':
            disp.innerHTML ="This Is Waste Type 3.";
            break;
        case 'WASTE4':
            disp.innerHTML ="This Is Waste Type 4.";
            break;
        default:
            myTimer = setTimeout( function () { document.getElementById( 'updateform' ).reset(); }, 2000 );
            disp.innerHTML = 'The text does not match. Form will be reset!!.';
            break;
    }
}

document.getElementById( 'updateform' ).addEventListener( 'reset', function () {
  clearTimeout( myTimer )
} )
```

```html
<form action="dbupdate.php" method="post" id="updateform" name="updateform">
    <label for="bcno">Item ID: </label>
    <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" name="bcno" id="bcno" oninput="showData()" autocomplete="off" />
    <span id="display"></span>
    <br>
    <label for="ino">Quantity: </label>
    <input type="number" id="ino" name="ino" value="1" />
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I solved my immediate problem I have another program where I can use your snippet.